# Show short cut NOT used

Tags: interface, add-on, shortcut

Is there a setting or add-on to show the shortcut if they are not used, i.e. the functions used with the mouse?

There is a plugin for IntelliJ called "Key Promoter X" which does exactly this:
If a function is used multiple times with the mouse a small popup appears telling you the shortcut.
If none exists, it advises you to create one.

This would be very helpful for me as a beginner to mesmerize the vast amount of Blenders shortcut just while using Blender.

Comment: I deleted my answer, since this was not what you were looking for. There is no add-on that reminds you to use a shortcut instead of e.g. using the menu, as far as I'm aware. However, menus entries do tell you the shortcut and you can enable tooltips in the preferences (*Edit > Preferences > Interface*) that show you additional information such as the shortcut when hovering over e.g. tools.

Comment: I'm sorry maybe you should follow what robert says.
Alternatively, you can study the blender manual on shortcuts and see which one you need most. A predictive add-on would be convenient for everyone. There is also an android app `` Blender Keys '' but I don't know how updated it is, I recommend the manual. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/keymap/introduction.html